# In GCP IAM what's the difference between "Viewer" and "BigQuery Data Viewer"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, permissions, google-iam, identity-management

I am trying to grant access to a table and cannot tell the difference between the "Viewer" and "BigQuery Data Viewer" roles. I do not want to give permissions to view other tables or datasets within the GCP Project or full access to BigQuery. Can someone tell me the difference between these two if the access is given through the Share option at the table level?

[Screenshot of where Role is granted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMBOK.png)

At the moment I've assigned the user both roles and am not sure if I'm granting too much access. I want to follow the Principle of Least Privilege.

Answer (score 0):

**Viewer** or `roles/viewer` is a top level, project level permission. Permissions for read-only actions that do not affect state, such as viewing (but not modifying) existing resources or data.

**BigQuery Data Viewer** its a resource based permission. Can be applied to BigQuery itself, or even to individual tables or views. Read all [about its usage](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#bigquery.dataViewer).

it has the following BQ roles:

```
bigquery.datasets.get
bigquery.datasets.getIamPolicy
bigquery.models.export
bigquery.models.getData
bigquery.models.getMetadata
bigquery.models.list
bigquery.routines.get
bigquery.routines.list
bigquery.tables.createSnapshot
bigquery.tables.export
bigquery.tables.get
bigquery.tables.getData
bigquery.tables.getIamPolicy
bigquery.tables.list
resourcemanager.projects.get
resourcemanager.projects.list
```

Comment: What happens when you add the Viewer role to a Principal but at the level of the table (like in the screenshot)? Would that user have read access for the whole project?

Comment: That's a good question. As long as you have a resource defined such as table, it should not let access to other products, its safe to use. I would say it's a bad user experience and bad habit allowing these top level roles. Better use individual roles.